# Why there are so many mathematicians on Academia.SE?

Tags: discussion, community

This is probably OT, but I'm curious: why there are so many mathematicians here? It seems to me that the overall community is made by people who study/research  math. Even undergrads post questions. Given that (at least in my country), math workers are a tiny fraction of the (academic) population, this seems an exception.

Comment: You can see the results of an informal poll here: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/470/929

Comment: Uh, great.  Thanks.

Comment: Lone anthropologist here. Studying the natives (not really).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mathematics is certainly disproportionately represented here, although it's only a minority of the site.

One reason is [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), which is arguably the most successful stackexchange site devoted to research-level academics.  As a consequence, the stackexchange network probably has more visibility within mathematics than in any other academic field except computer science itself.  When non-technical questions come up on MathOverflow, people are often advised to come here instead, so we get a steady stream of visitors interested in mathematics.

A second reason is critical mass.  If a mathematics student or professor visits this site, they will quickly see that it's a welcoming and useful place to ask/answer questions, while this may be less apparent in some other fields.  The net result is that first-time users in mathematics are probably more likely to become active participants.

Answer (score 10):

The general "tilt" of SE sites is towards math and computer science, so it's not much of a stretch that such disciplines would be well-represented here.